# Application not loading on facebook

Tags: facebook

I am new in facebook application development and i have developed a simple game Tic Tac Toe and hosted it. i provided the directory URL in the canvas Url. The problem is that the canvas loads but the game does not load.
here is the game url

http://test.waysandmeanstechnology.us/TicTacToe/tictactoe.html

Comment: When you are accessing Facebook via HTTPS (as most users do, and _all_ users will in the near future), your app must be available via HTTPS too – but your app seems not to be.